# Saving and opening an attachment in Android Q and later

Tags: java, android

I am maintaining a legacy Java / C++ application for Android which is backwards compatible to some API 18. It contains a rudimentary e-mail client.

Users receive e-mails with various attachments (HTML, PDF, JPG, MP3, MP4, XLS) and want to be able to open them in external applications. Prior to Android Q, I just saved the attachments to disk and invoked an intent with ACTION_VIEW on the file:///uri to the saved attachment.

This stopped working in Android Q with the new restrictions on storage access. Even if I save a HTML file to, say, Download/ directory, Chrome won't open it from an ACTION_VIEW intent: the error is ERR_ACCESS_DENIED.

I don't know how to fix this problem with the new scoped storage. Is there even a unified way how to open file types as different as PDF, HTML, JPG, MP3, MP4, XLS in external applications using intents? Or do I have to branch my code according to the type of the media and use some different approaches and directories for images, sounds, video and documents?

Is ACTION_VIEW still universally capable of opening files such as HTML, or has it been restricted to media files only? I would be happy to have an universal way of opening all temporarily saved attachments (smaller code to maintain is always better), but I am not sure if it is possible at all anymore.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `on the file:///uri to the saved attachment.` You have to use FIleProvider to serve your file now adays.

Comment: `This stopped working in Android Q with the new restrictions on storage access. ` No. That is coincidal. The point is that you now have to use FileProvider for the action you use.

Comment: So I declare FileProvider in my application manifest, name my own application as android:authorities and then I can allow other applications to access files that I own via intent? Will the apps let me know that they are finished with the file, so that I can delete it again?

Comment: `I can allow other applications to access files` I dont know what you mean by that. Better show your code. Also your manifest code for the provider. And no, you will not be informed when apps are finished.